# Rename an Excel worksheet based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I tried searching the web and Stack; however, I couldn't find anything useful. I'm trying to create a very simple event in which a worksheet is renamed when a cell value doesn't contain illegal characters.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Target = Sh.Cells(1, 1)
If InStr(Target, "\") > 0 Or IsEmpty(Target) = True _
    Or InStr(Target, "/") > 0 Or InStr(Target, "*") > 0 _
    Or InStr(Target, "[") > 0 Or InStr(Target, "]") > 0 _
    Or InStr(Target, ":") > 0 Or InStr(Target, "?") > 0 Then
Else
    Sh.Name = Target
End If

End Sub
```

It's supposed to work like this: If value in A1 contains all legal characters, rename the sheet. That is indeed happening but it also changes any value I put to any other cell to the name of the sheet. Any advice?

Comment: Use `Intersect()` to test *Target*

Comment: Not sure what you really trying to do but `Target` is the cell range which has changed and so has triggered the event. And with `Target = Sh.Cells(1, 1)` you are overwriting this cell range with `Sh.Cells(1, 1).Value`. So what exactly are you trying to do? Renaming the sheet with  `Sh.Cells(1, 1).Value`? But then why on changing every cell?

Comment: I want A1 in each sheet to be in control of the name of that sheet. That is the case but as a side effect it also rewrites any value inserted anywhere else in the sheet.

Comment: So you want to do the whole thing only `IF Target.Address = "$A$1"`?

Comment: Yes, i want only one cell on each sheet - A1 - to be in charge of the name of the sheet. Everything else as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, s As String

    Set ws = Target.Parent
    Set r = Intersect(Target, ws.Range("A1"))

    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    s = r.Value
    If InStr(s, "\") > 0 Or s = "" _
        Or InStr(s, "/") > 0 Or InStr(s, "*") > 0 _
        Or InStr(s, "[") > 0 Or InStr(s, "]") > 0 _
        Or InStr(s, ":") > 0 Or InStr(s, "?") > 0 Then
    Else
        Sh.Name = s
    End If
End Sub
```

NOTE:

The code does not check for re-using a value.

Comment: Why not using `Sh` but using `Target.Parent` instead?

Comment: @AxelRichter  In the past, I have had problems if cells on different worksheets are changed simultaneously.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. What was the problem? I thought that the Target was defined.

Comment: @OndraLepša  The primary problem with the original coding is that ***Target*** should be *examined* and not `Set`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the method below as you can predefine the list of invalid characters without having to hard-code them in the `If..End If` block:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngA1OfSheet As Range
    Dim varInvalidChars As Variant
    Dim varTest As Variant
    Dim blnCheck1 As Boolean
    Dim blnCheck2 As Boolean

    Set rngA1OfSheet = Sh.Range("A1")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngA1OfSheet) Is Nothing Then
        blnCheck1 = IsEmpty(rngA1OfSheet.Value)

        varInvalidChars = Array("\", "/", "*", "[", "]", ":", "?")
        blnCheck2 = False
        For Each varTest In varInvalidChars
            If InStr(1, rngA1OfSheet.Value, CStr(varTest), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                blnCheck2 = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Not blnCheck1 And Not blnCheck2 Then
            Sh.Name = rngA1OfSheet.Value
        End If

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: That's a neat way to do it! Thank you!